# Element ID not available till navigating to DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm loading the SVG file on form submission and trying to click the element but I am not able to find the element by ID. Element id is available after navigating to DOM. How to get element? Tried loading the svg file **window.onload** but no luck.

```
document.getElementById('G-Group');
null
```

after navigate to browser dev tools:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1" d="m 873.6268,509.7384 c -0.24555,5.40185 -0.49109,10.8037 -0.73664,16.20555 -4.33361,-1.57148 -8.81028,-4.50147 -12.5237,-0.18338 -2.39215,2.09564 -2.08486,10.2611 2.0028,10.9329 3.77971,3.39045 8.28702,-5.1211 11.32814,-1.90533 0.46754,4.90918 0.93508,9.81835 1.40262,14.72753 5.64739,0 11.29479,0 16.94218,0 0.98215,-10.06709 1.96431,-20.13417 2.94646,-30.20126 -7.12062,-3.192 -14.24124,-6.38401 -21.36186,-9.57601 z" id="G1"/>
```

after navigating to

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); setTimeout(showhide('svgContainer','FloorPlan_V2.svg'), 3000);">
        <select id="filename">
            <option value="FloorPlan_V1.svg">Floor 1</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Find Seats" />
    </form>
    <div id="svgContainer">
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showhide(id, svg) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  if (!element.getElementsByTagName("object").length) {
    var object = document.createElement("object");
    object.type = "image/svg+xml";
    object.data = svg;
    object.id = id+'1';
    element.appendChild(object);
    //D3.JS 
    d3.select('#G-Group').selectAll('path').style("fill","red");

} 

}
```

Comment: Can you please create working instance (jsfiddle) for your issue ?

Comment: Where in your html did you define an element with id `G-Group` ?

Comment: the ID will be available in FloorPlan_V2.svg file on form submission

Comment: Hello @SandeepGouda ! Have you checked out my answer? Have I been able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the `object`'s document, you need to use its [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property. Note that this will only be accessible if the `object`'s data has the same origin as the containing document.

Access the `object`'s DOM in the `load` event, for example like this:

```js
function showhide(id, svg) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  if (!element.getElementsByTagName("object").length) {
    const object = document.createElement("object");
    object.type = "image/svg+xml";
    object.id = id + '1';

    object.onload = function() {
      const paths = object.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('#G-Group path');
      for (const path of paths) {
        path.style.fill = "red";
      }
    }

    object.data = svg;
    element.appendChild(object);
  }
}
```